# openSuse 42.2 is unable to boot when root is on RAID1 which is broken (with one missing/new/empty disk)

Tags: linux, boot, opensuse, raid, dracut

Here is the case:

I have two disks setup in RAID 1 as follows:

- `/dev/md0` (`/dev/sda1` + `/dev/sdb1`) → `/boot`
- `/dev/md1` (`/dev/sda2` + `/dev/sdb2`) → `/`

My scenario:

1. Start server with RAID 1 and array fully synchronized
2. Shut down my server normally
3. Remove one of the disks (`/dev/sdb`)
4. Try booting again with just one disk

My scenario is working well on openSuse 11.3 → 42.1

On openSuse 42.2, when I try to boot with one disk only, GRUB loads fine (while also located on an array), but later on it waits forever for the root (`/dev/md1`) device. I would expect it to break the array and go on.

I tested it with new install of 42.2 from DVD (with and without zypper update), as well as online distro upgrade from 42.1. Same issue in all scenarios.

If array was already broken before shutdown, it does boot well (with broken array).

I also tested specifying RAID devices on the command line: `linux .... root=/dev/md1 md=1 /dev/sda2,/dev/sdb2` (see picture), but it did not help.

Screenshots are available in my ticket open on openSuse Bugzilla: https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1017695

Getting this solved is critical for me since I have already had several issues at client sites where "hard shutdown" (electrical (battery) power failure, common in Central America) damages a disk, leading to a similar scenario as the one described above. I can't upgrade to openSuse 42.2 if I can't fix this problem in some way.

Please note that the boot loader (GRUB2) seems not to be the issue, since I can boot on any disk and GRUB always loads correctly (although `/boot` is also on a RAID 1 partition). Problem is later on, when mounting the root file system. Possibly an issue with `dracut-pre-mount` script?

All ideas are welcome...

Answer (score 0):

Is actually confirmed as an openSuse bug. A dracut config file is missing...

Workaround is described here: https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1017695